# Как проверять существует ли такое значение в базе данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql, count

Всем привет, у меня такая задачка:
Допустим у меня есть ID 10 и есть поля со значениями KPID (int) в базе, мне нужно проверять есть ли 10 в базе KPID
Если нет то KPID будет 10 если есть 11, 12, 13...
Но есть еще одна загвоздка, нужно считать не с последнего значение в базе KPID, нужно именно чтобы так скажем отсчет начинался с 10, есть: 10, 12, 13, 14, 15 тут нету 11, значит нам нужно задать KPID 11 вместо 15+...
Надеюсь правильно обьяснился, всем спасибо заранее, жду ваших версий :)

Comment: Совершенно ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переформулируем сложно описанную задачу.

Есть у нас некий ID со значением `int`.
Есть БД, а там - некое единственное "поле" (столбец, вероятно, если по ANSI) KPID.
Если в этом стобце есть значение, равное ID, то надо добавить еще кортеж со значением, равным первому отсутствующему, начиная со значения ID.

Проверять существование (задача, поставленная в заголовке) просто:

```
SELECT MIN (KPID)
FROM имя таблицы 
WHERE KPID >= ID;
```

На выходе будет минимальное значение, равное или большее ID.
Если равно, значит - есть ID, если больше - значит, нет ID в БД.

Comment: Это не решает проблему автора. Допустим `ID = 10`, запрос вернет 10, а ему 10 не нужно, ему нужно минимальный неиспользуемый, ну вот как в примере - 11.

Comment: Есть ясная формулировка вопроса: "Как проверять существует ли такое значение в базе данных mysql?". Этот ответ полностью отвечает на поставленный вопрос, что я специально указал в ответе.

Comment: По-моему, очевидно, что в заголовке _весь_ вопрос обычно не помещается. Обычно, нужно читать текст тоже и особенно примеры. Не писать же в заголовке "Как проверять существует ли такое значение в базе данных mysql, и если существует, то возвращать минимальное неиспользуемое большее заданного"

Comment: "Вопрос по нахождению минимального пропущенного значения в ряду чисел". В конечном счете, я дал тот ответ, который мог на текущем минимальном уровне знания mySQL и отсутствии знания php. Возможно, автору поможет. Кто-то  может дать более полный ответ - всегда приветствуется.

Comment: Из-за того, что человек (новичек на сайте) не смог выразить в заголовке суть вопроса, вы даете ему ответ не на его вопрос.

Comment: Человек получает нужную ему выгрузку из БД. Может пройти по ней циклом в поисках первого же отсутствующего элемента. И повторюсь: дал тот ответ, который могу. Больше - не могу. Кто-то может дать более полный ответ - всегда приветствуется. Не дадут, будет у человека этот ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое так тоже можно :) про SELECT MIN я не знал